# How to get FitNesse root or page folder in FitSharp

Tags: path, fitnesse, fitsharp

Recently I encountered this problem and have searched a lot but no solution by now. 
Does somebody know how I can get the root directory or the page folder of FitNesse in FitSharp fixture codes? 
One of the troubles is that we have a lot of existing pages arranged in different suites and I want to add some new features to all these pages requiring an absolute path of FitNesse folder. Using a fixture together with the environmental parameter in pages could require a lot of effort. I was even trying to use hard configuration in app.config for example!

Big thanks in advance! Looking forward to your kind answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root path is available as a FitNesse predefined variable.  Pass that into a fixture that can expose it as a property.  This could go in a setup page.

```
|rootpath|
|load|${FITNESSE_ROOTPATH}|

public class RootPath {
  public static string Path;
  public void Load(string value) { Path = value;}
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mike! I'm sorry I was really busy this month and put this problem aside for a while. Now I come back to it. The idea you mentioned is really practical. So it was also my first idea. But the problem is we already have a lot of pages and they are using quite a set of different set up pages. If do so, I'll have to modify quite a lot of set up pages. So may I ask you if there is any other approach? Or how can I improve this one?

Comment: Maybe put it on a SuiteSetUp page?  This is included once at the start of running a suite.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Mike. I know what you mean and I totally agree it will make it easy. But currently, pages are running with different SuiteSetUp pages. Yes, we have a suite for all pages, but all the "sub suite" has its own dedicated SuiteSetUp. What can I do with this case? Thanks in advance!